# Route for annotation methods in traefik-ingress with kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, traefik

I need to route methods like PUT, PATCH, GET and POST in two different URLs, but I didn't find the best entry for my entry pod. I tried the annotation he used, but it doesn't work. Could you help me with this?

edit yaml added

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    traefik.frontend.rule: PathPrefixStrip;Method:PUT,PATCH,POST
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/frontend-entry-points: http,https
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  name: services-ingress-xx-api-mock
  namespace: develop-v1-0
spec:
  rules:
  - host: xx
    http:    
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: xx-api-mock
          servicePort: http
        path: xx/xxx
  tls:
  - secretName: mysecret
```

Comment: It might help get more useful answers if you include the annotation you tried

Comment: traefik.frontend.rule: "PathPrefixStrip;Method:PUT,PATCH,POST"

I used this annotation, but it doesn't work.

Comment: which version of Traefik are you on?

Comment: i'm use traefik 1.7.9

Comment: Could you put here your YAML configuration?

Comment: @PjoterS this is my service ingress yaml